# Updating Composer on Yii2 - Missing dependencies

Tags: php, yii2, composer-php, bower

I had to backup the whole application to move it into another server, after setting up all the requirements I tried running "composer update" and I found a couple of problems I'm not being able to fix because of lack of experience.

Below are the problems:

**Problem 1**
- Root composer.json requires miloschuman/yii2-highcharts-widget ^6.0 -> satisfiable by miloschuman/yii2-highcharts-widget[v6.0].
- miloschuman/yii2-highcharts-widget v6.0 requires bower-asset/highcharts ^6.0 -> could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

**Problem 2**
- Root composer.json requires russ666/yii2-countdown ^0.1.0 -> satisfiable by russ666/yii2-countdown[0.1].
- russ666/yii2-countdown 0.1 requires bower-asset/jquery.countdown * -> could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

This is my composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-basic",
    "description": "Yii 2 Basic Project Template",
    "keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "basic", "project template"],
    "homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "support": {
        "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
        "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
        "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
        "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
        "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "yidas/yii2-composer-bower-skip": "~2.0.5",             
        "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.5",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "~2.0.0",
        "dmstr/yii2-adminlte-asset": "2.*",
        "hguenot/yii2-gsftp": "*",
        "ext-bz2": "*",
        "edvlerblog/yii2-adldap-module": "^1.1.2",
        "miloschuman/yii2-highcharts-widget": "dev-master",
        "mtdowling/cron-expression": "^1.1",
        "kartik-v/yii2-field-range": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widgets": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-date-range": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-grid": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-mpdf": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-export": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-sidenav": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-nav-x": "*",
        "yii2mod/yii2-ftp": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-tabs-x": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-typeahead": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-editable": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-money": "*",
        "sunra/php-simple-html-dom-parser": "v1.5.0",        
        "xj/snoopy": "2.0.0",
        "vova07/yii2-console-runner-extension": "*",
        "hscstudio/yii2-export": "1.0.0",
        "omnilight/yii2-scheduling": "*",
        "himiklab/yii2-recaptcha-widget": "*",
        "dts/ebay-sdk-php": "^7.0",
        "mongosoft/yii2-soap-client": "*",
        "exeu/apai-io": "~2.0",
        "authorizenet/authorizenet": "1.9.2",
        "kop/yii2-scroll-pager": "dev-master",
        "alfallouji/dhl_api": "^0.2.10",
        "vinceg/usps-php-api": "^1.0",
        "gabrielbull/ups-api": "^0.7.11",
        "jeremy-dunn/php-fedex-api-wrapper": "dev-master",
        "russ666/yii2-countdown": "^0.1.0",
        "dsposito/argo": "^2.0",
        "impgds/rocketshipit": "dev-master" ,
        "ujjwal/currency-converter":"2.2.*",
        "tawba/currency-converter": "^1.7",
        "bestbuy/bestbuy": "^1.0",
        "paquettg/php-html-parser": "^1.7",
        "picqer/php-barcode-generator": "^0.2.1",
        "sorich87/bootstrap-tour": "*@dev",
        "mycademy/yii2-bootstrap-tour": "*@dev",
        "moonlandsoft/yii2-phpexcel": "*",
        "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet" : "*@dev",
        "fabpot/goutte": "^3.2",
        "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "^1.2",
        "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "^1.3",
        "jonnyw/php-phantomjs": "4.*",
        "dmore/chrome-mink-driver": "^2.6",
        "facebook/webdriver": "^1.6",
        "stichoza/google-translate-php": "^3.2",
        "docta/mercadolibre": "^1.0",
        "dejurin/php-google-translate-for-free": "^1.0",
        "viniciusgava/google-translate-api": "^2.0",
        "serps/search-engine-google": "^0.4.6",
        "guzzlehttp/psr7": "^1.5",
        "zendframework/zend-diactoros": "^1.8",
        "serps/http-client-curl": "^0.2.3",
        "components/font-awesome": "^5.15"
        
        
        
    },
 
    
    "require-dev": {
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "~2.0.0",
        "codeception/base": "^2.2.3",
        "codeception/verify": "~0.3.1",
        "codeception/specify": "~0.4.3",
        "behat/mink": "^1.7",
        "behat/mink-zombie-driver": "dev-master",
        "simpletest/simpletest": "^1.1"
        
    },
    "config": {
        "process-timeout": 1800,
        "fxp-asset": {
            "installer-paths": {
                "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
                "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
            }
        },
        "allow-plugins": {
            "composer/installers": false,
            "yiisoft/yii2-composer": true
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "yii\\composer\\Installer::postCreateProject"
        ]
        
    },
    "extra": {
        "yii\\composer\\Installer::postCreateProject": {
            "setPermission": [
                {
                    "runtime": "0777",
                    "web/assets": "0777",
                    "yii": "0755"
                }
            ],
            "generateCookieValidationKey": [
                "config/web.php"
            ]
        }
        
    }
}
```

I've researched the 2 problems listed, as per the documentation those packages require bower-assets, I installed bower but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: If any package you want to use uses any other package that does not exist (like `bower-asset/highcharts`), you should contact whoever maintains that package. Also, v6 of `miloschuman/yii2-highcharts-widget` is more than four years old - maybe you want to update the package?

Comment: Same for `russ666/yii2-countdown`  - v0.1 of that package is **seven years** old....

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what version you want to upgrade. Or which version of php are you using? For example the upgrade from [Yii 2.0.12](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2.0.44/framework/UPGRADE.md#upgrade-from-yii-2012) is very important.

Follow the instructions on this [page](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2.0.44/framework/UPGRADE.md):

> Note: The following upgrading instructions are cumulative. That is, if
> you want to upgrade from version A to version C and there is version B
> between A and C, you need to follow the instructions for both A and B.

To ensure best stability you should also upgrade composer in this step:

```
composer self-update
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:^1.4.1" --no-plugins
```

Yii2 expects Bower and NPM packages to be installed to vendor/bower and vendor/npm folders respectively.

So, to use asset-packagist for Yii2 projects it's necessary to reassign Bower and NPM aliases in your application config like this:

```
$config = [
    ...
    'aliases' => [
        '@bower' => '@vendor/bower-asset',
        '@npm'   => '@vendor/npm-asset',
    ],
    ...
];
```

Migrating from composer-asset-plugin
Moving from composer-asset-plugin is not straightforward when you host several applications on single server. It's known that asset packagist and asset plugin don't work well together when plugin is installed in global scope. So, to not affect other applications by deleting the plugin, you may disable the plugin locally via composer.json config option (you need plugin version ≥ 1.3.0 for this):

```
"config": {
    "fxp-asset": {
        "enabled": false
    }
}
```

[Source Link](https://asset-packagist.org/site/about)